# driver = webdriver.Chrome(DRIVER, options=options) TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'options'

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, chromedriver

Подскажите где может крыться ошибка:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(DRIVER, options=options)
TypeError: __init__() got multiple values for argument 'options'
```

Привожу пример своего кода;

```
import requests
import os
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
options.add_argument("--headless")  
options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--disable-crash-reporter")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--disable-in-process-stack-traces")
options.add_argument("--disable-logging")
options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
options.add_argument("--output=/dev/null")
DRIVER = 'chromedriver'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(DRIVER, options=options)
```

Установлен Хром 114,Винда 10.Пайтон 3.7.7

Comment: В заголовке вопроса должна быть его краткая суть.

Comment: А что за ошибки, какого поведения хотите добиться?